# Is there an alternative to the: as_integer_ratio(), for getting "cleaner" fractions?

Tags: python

I know I can use:
- 0.5.as_integer_ratio() ; and get the integer fraction: 1/2

However, if I have a decimal such as:
- 8.333333333333334 ; which is equivalent to: 25/3 ; and I use the 8.333333333333334.as_integer_ratio() ; I get: (4691061961859793, 562949953421312)

Is there a function/way to get to the "clean" 25/3 instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you want exact representation of fractions like 25/3, you shouldn't be doing your math in floating point in the first place. You should use an exact rational type, like [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html):

```
from fractions import Fraction
x = Fraction(75)
y = x/9
print(y)
```

Output:

```
25/3
```

If you're stuck with a floating-point number or a decimal string, you can convert it to a `Fraction` and use [`limit_denominator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) to find a nearby fraction with a small denominator. By default, "small" is treated as <= 1000000, but you can configure the limit.

```
print(Fraction(8.333333333333334).limit_denominator())
```

Output:

```
25/3
```

Handling everything in rational arithmetic from the start is almost always better, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by importing python modules @Fraction and @Decimal, so let see how to it works:

from decimal import Decimal from fractions import Fraction

Fraction(Decimal('8.33333333333334')).limit_denominator()

Note: the limit_denominator is was is going to simplify your fraction to the lowest value as possible. And the argument passed to the Decimal must be in quotes

Comment: The Decimal call is *still* pointless, even if you're passing it a string instead of a float like you did in your previous, deleted version of this answer.

Comment: Then how to fix it? Where is the issue?

Comment: `Fraction` already handles floats and strings. The `Decimal` call can simply be removed.

Comment: Ok, I got the point, but anyway it works well, and that was the case in python 2.6, now I can see it was become optional

Comment: `Fraction` didn't take `Decimal` instances in 2.6, so the `Decimal` call would have been outright wrong back then, not just pointless.